# Conversation XMPP client receives last message on every reconnect to Openfire server

Tags: android, client, xmpp, openfire

I used Openfire server with Conversation xmpp client on Android, everything is working well. But the problem is that clients receive last message on every reconnect.

It would be great to know if someone has the solution.

Comment: What is the problem? You don't want any "history" messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by comparing new received message with messages stored in local database on their STANZA. Then I ignore messages which is already stored in database.